# Jquery mobile multiple select not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am sure this did work, I am building a phonegap app with the latest jquery-mobile 1.4, But with ios 7 my multiple select native does not work anymore. I can only select one option. If i add data-role="none" then it does work but i loose the jquery mobile theme. Has anybody came across this and have a fix.

```
<script>
    $.getJSON(
        "http://m.mysite.com/ajaxResponder.php?method=getContacts",
        function(data) {
            var items = "";

            if (data.none != 'none') {
                items +='<legend><span lang="en">Select Contacts</span></legend>'+
                            '<select name="contacts[]" multiple="multiple"  data-native-menu="true">';                                      
                $.each(data.contacts, function(index, item) {
                    items += "<option value='" + item.email + "'>" + item.names + "</option>";
                });
                items += '</select>';
            }
            else {
                items +='<span lang="en">Contacts will be displayed here. They can be created from the contacts menu</span>';
            }
            $("#contacts").html(items);
            $("#contacts").trigger("create");
        }
    );
<script>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <div id="contacts"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: multi-select works only with `data-native-menu="false"` as jQM converts `select` into a popup or a dialog. If you apply `data-role="none"` it will work but without jQM styles.

Comment: Thanks Omar for the clarification. I must have always selected one name when i was testing earlier and never thought it was going to be a problem, Shame as it is a great looking feature

Comment: I was finding that all desktop browsers failed to work as expected with jQuery mobile select inputs. When the tag was `<select multiple="multiple" id="id_permissions" name="permissions">` it functioned as expected on iOS devices and failed on the desktop. Set to `<select multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" id="id_permissions" name="permissions">` it functioned on the desktop. Your comment saved a lot of headache! Thank you.

Comment: Here is the jquery mobile documentation for my above comment: https://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#option-nativeMenu

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any luck?

Comment: Hi Shahar, Sorry for the late response, The truth is you can't use native multiple select.